# Retrieving data from SOAP API

Tags: soap, cxf, exacttarget

I am trying to retrieve 3000 records from Exact Target SOAP API using Apache CXF. 
They return upto 2500 records per response. Thus I get "MoreDataAvailable", but I cannot get the remaining data.

Here is the code:

```
// Retrieve data
RetrieveRequestMsg retrieveRequestMsg = new RetrieveRequestMsg();
retrieveRequestMsg.setRetrieveRequest( retrieveRequest );
RetrieveResponseMsg retrieveResponseMsg = stub.retrieve( retrieveRequestMsg );
//System.out.println( "\n [Sends][overall status message] " + retrieveResponseMsg.getOverallStatus() );
results = retrieveResponseMsg.getResults();

while (retrieveResponseMsg.getOverallStatus().equals("MoreDataAvailable"))
{
    // FIXME: THis does not work for some reason :(
    retrieveResponseMsg = stub.retrieve( retrieveRequestMsg );        
    results.addAll(retrieveResponseMsg.getResults());
}
```

It does not work - simply adds more of the old records...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to do a completely new request and setContinueRequest to the ID of the previous response message:

```
if (retrieveResponseMsg.getOverallStatus().equals(
        "MoreDataAvailable")) {
    RetrieveRequest retrieveRequestCont = new RetrieveRequest();
    retrieveRequestCont.setContinueRequest(retrieveResponseMsg
            .getRequestID());
    RetrieveRequestMsg retrieveRequestMsgCont = new RetrieveRequestMsg();
    retrieveRequestMsgCont.setRetrieveRequest(retrieveRequestCont) ;

    RetrieveResponseMsg retrieveResponseMsgCont = stub
            .retrieve(retrieveRequestMsgCont);
    System.out.println("[overall status message] "
            + retrieveResponseMsgCont.getOverallStatus());
    apiObjectArray = retrieveResponseMsgCont.getResults();
} else {
    cont = false;
}
```

I found it here:
https://code.exacttarget.com/question/how-get-more-2500-records-using-java